# Can't make a set a summation of members

Tags: tableau-api

I am super new to Tableau so this may be a dumb question but I am trying to create a visualization where I can see sales based off of the region that the sale was made in. The regions are sets that I made by creating a maps visualization and then using the lasso feature to manually group the data point. The issue I'm having is that now that I try to use these sets, they aren't acting as a summation of all the points in them. I can only have one in a visualization at a time to even get any data. This is what it looks like with just the midwest group in the visualization (it specifies sales for each location but I don't want that, I just want a summation.
[image]

This is what it looks like if I try to add in another set
[image]

I've looked around and everything that I have found is saying that I should just extract the set and then I'll be able to click on the option to Show in/out of set but I don't have the option to extract if I right click on the set in the left column. Is there something that I'm missing? Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Sounds like creating groups is more appropriate for what you want than creating sets. https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/sortgroup_groups_creating.htm

Comment: I agree with @AndyTARSols.  But while creating group (paperclip icon), please keep in mind that any element can be a member of multiple sets but only of one group at a time.

Comment: When I create the groups, they all get added to the same one but are different parts of it, is this how groups are supposed to work?

Comment: Groups works like creating an upper hierarchial level of existing dimension.  Like e.g. imagine dimension having values (categorical) say v1, to v10.  These can be regrouped like group1 having v1, v2; group2 having v3, and v5 and remaining all other in group3.